# Nginx proxy_pass rule Issue

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

So, I'm running some docker containers serving on ports 8090 and 8000. Now I want to setup Nginx reverse proxy to handle requests to both of these ports internally. The main URL http://milesblock.com changes automatically to http://milesblock.com/#/

I have setup a proxy_pass in nginx as follows-

```
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  milesblock.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {

           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
       }


       location /api {

            rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
    }
```

Now, the issue is because of the automatic change of the URL to http://milesblock.com/#/ the redirect to both the ports is not working as intended. Only the /api proxy is working with the above config file.

How do i configure the proxy to handle the traffic on port 8090 and also the api calls on port 8000?

Comment: Why did you put `root         /usr/share/nginx/html;` ? Are you serving static content from `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder?

Comment: @mgsxman It was just the default config file that I took and wrote the proxy_pass rules, was not sure about the root directory option.

Comment: Everything that goes after the `#` sign (called *fragment* in terms of URI parts) has nothing to do with nginx (or any other web server). It isn't even became the part of HTTP request that the browser send to web server.